# What is the difference between using list[num] and len(list[num]) in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, codeskulptor

As part of the project, I am supposed to build a memory game, which involves randomizing a list of 16 digits (two identical ranges of range(7)) and printing those digits onto a canvas. My first iteration had a for loop that picks each number of the list and prints it onto the canvas at a set interval (middle_cell_point) as such:

```
def draw(canvas):

    middle_counter = 1

    for num in full_list:

        canvas.draw_text(str(full_list[num]), (((middle_cell_point * middle_counter)) 
                          - (middle_cell_point/2) , HEIGHT/2), 22, "Red")
        middle_counter += 1
```

the output from this repeats numbers on the canvas, but when I debug the code it seems to accurately assign numbers and does not seem to repeat any. The program works properly When I replaced "full_list" with "range(len(full_list))" in the for-loop:

```
def draw(canvas):

    middle_counter = 1

    for num in range(len(full_list)):

        canvas.draw_text(str(full_list[num]), (((middle_cell_point * middle_counter)) 
                              - (middle_cell_point/2) , HEIGHT/2), 22, "Red")
        middle_counter += 1
```

could someone explain to me why the second iteration works and the first one does not?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are the values of `list(range(len(full_list)))` and `full_list` respectively?

Comment: Of you do `num in full_list`, you should not use `full_list[num]`, but just `num`

Comment: If you are interested in the index position and the current object of each iteration step, I recommend using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for that, e.g.: `for index, content in enumerate(full_list): ...`

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: hey AMC, got the answer I was looking for from Wolph below, was confused about index vs value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `for num in full_list` lists the items and `for num in range(len(full_list))` lists the indices.

To illustrate:

```py
>>> full_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(full_list)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(range(len(full_list)))
[0, 1, 2]
```

In your case you want to use `num` instead of `full_list[num]`:

```py
def draw(canvas):

    middle_counter = 1

    for num in full_list:

        canvas.draw_text(str(num), (((middle_cell_point * middle_counter)) 
                                    - (middle_cell_point/2) , HEIGHT/2), 22, "Red")
        middle_counter += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! makes sense about the index vs item. One question about using num instead, my initial thought is that it would just pull the current "num" being used in the for loop, not the relevant value in the list. I tested it and it works, but I do not fully understand why.

Comment: @FelipeBerger perhaps this helps: `for value in array`. It's enumerating the values in the array :) To help you further, try this as well: `for i, value in enumerate(array)` to get both the index and the value

Answer (score 0):

The first one iterates through the values of the initial vector si resulta are not correct. 
The second one iterates through the indexes if the vector from one to the Max length si valúes are correct